# Why is "df -T" showing only one hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive

I just ordered server which the hard disk spec is `2 x 1.5TB`

but when using `df -T` only showing 1.5TB:

```
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/hda1     ext3   1417219800   1243220 1342824608   1% /
tmpfs        tmpfs     4150720         0   4150720   0% /dev/shm
```

running `mount`:

```
/dev/hda1 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

Comment: Is the other drive mounted? What does `mount` say?

Comment: running `mount` has been added above

Comment: Check the output from "fdisk -l" or "parted -l" to determine if there are multiple physical drives connected.  You can really easily see this if you do "parted -l|grep Model|grep -v device-mapper"

Comment: what does `dmesg` say? Does it find two drives?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using df try using [fdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) e.g.

```
fdisk -l | grep '^Disk'

Disk /dev/sda: 12.8 GB, 12884901888 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 10 GB, 1048576000 bytes
```

This will list the detected disks in the system.

df will only list information about mounted filesystems.

Edit:

If this is a Solaris system you can use `format` to list the disks the system knows about

```
#format </dev/null
Searching for disks ... done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
        0. c1t0d0 <DEFAULT  cyl 1563 alt 2 hd 64 sec 32>
           /pci@0,0/pci15ad,1976@10/sd@0,0
        1. c1t1d0 <VMware-Virtual disk-1.0-200.00MB>>
           /pci@0,0/pci15ad,1976@10/sd@1,0
specify disk (enter its number):
#
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a server, aren't those 2 disks configured as RAID 1? If so, the output is correct. RAID 1 is mirroring, so if you have 2 disks one of them is used to mirror the data from the other, effectively leaving you with `SUM OF DISK SPACES / 2`.

You will have to check the POST of the server to see if there's anything related to RAID and check if it is indeed a RAID 1 configuration. It can be at the setup too, or a message during POST giving a key combination to enter a *Disk Management Interface* or something close to that.